# Tridion UI interfering with 404 - creating directories

Tags: experience-manager

I'm running Tridion 2011 SP1 & having an issue getting Tridion UI 2012 to work correctly.

Simply - when I navigate to a URL that should return a 404 (non-existent directories or files), it doesn't return a 404 - instead, the directories are automatically created.

We recently applied hotfix CD_2011.1.1.82378 that prevents this behaviour on specific url paths (you add paths that should be ignored by Tridion UI to an 'excludedpaths' node in the cd_ambientconf.xml file), however for obvious reasons this will not work for paths that should return a 404.

Has anyone experienced this / know the solution?

Comment: Is it a ASP.NET website on IIS or a JSP website and if so what application server? I think I remember having this issue on IIS when my `web.config` didn't contain the `Tridion.ContentDelivery.Preview.Web.PreviewContentModule` httpModule.

Comment: ASP.NET website on IIS.  I spoke with SDL in the end - this is expected behaviour unfortunately.

Comment: Do we have a fix for this in 2013 SP1?? I am experiencing the same behaviour in 2013 SP1 Preview site. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is expected behaviour.

It is assumed Experience Manager will never be enabled on a live site, and so this issue will only arise in development or staging environments.